# Open AI - Maximum context length is 4097 tokens

Tags: php, chat, openai-api

I'm trying to use the completions api to find the best result to a given prompt. I'm using this PHP client: https://github.com/orhanerday/open-ai.

Currently, my approach to this is the following:

1. I have a table in my database where I store questions/answers, I query this table to bring all questions and answers stored.

An example of the array returned by the query is the following:

```
[
  [
    "question" => "question 1",
    "answer" => "answer 1",
    "action" => "action 1"
  ],
  [
    "question" => "question 2",
    "answer" => "answer 2",
    "action" => "action 2"
  ],
  ...
]
```

2. I convert the array returned by the query to a json string.
3. I call the completions api with the following prompt: `For each question-answer pair in this JSON object ' . $json_from_db . ', calculate the cosine similarity between the "question" column and [QUESTION-FROM-THE-USER]. If the similarity is greater than or equal to 0.6, provide a JSON string containing the corresponding "answer" value and the corresponding "action" value.`

```
$complete = $open_ai->completion([
            'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct',
            'prompt' => '', // THE PROMPT I JUST DESCRIBED ABOVE
            'temperature' => 0.2,
            'max_tokens' => 150,
            'frequency_penalty' => 0.8,
            'presence_penalty' => 0.0
]);
```

4. The ideal scenario is that it returns a json with the most appropriate answer to the user's question.

```
[
  {answer: 'answer 2', action: 'action 2'}
]
```

Instead I get this error: `This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens, however you requested 6426 tokens (6276 in your prompt; 150 for the completion). Please reduce your prompt; or completion length.`

This error wasn't appearing until I added more data to the table in the database.

Is this the best approach?

Comment: Presumably `$json_from_db` has gotten large enough to hit the limit. Break it into manageable chunks and make an API call for each, or use one of the GPT models that supports more tokens.